# REDIS not able to connect inside Ubuntu Docker Container

Tags: docker, redis

I have mac and installed docker on it.
I have created a container from latest ubuntu image.

This is my docker command:
`docker run -it --name ubuntu-container -p 6379:6379 ubuntu /bin/bash`

Now inside ubuntu container I am trying this

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y redis-tools
```

However, I am not able to run redis after successfully installing it inside Ubuntu Container.

```
root@14d6783b73b3:/# redis-cli ping
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

Since, I am new to docker and Redis, I am not able to understand the root cause itself.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for the [Docker Hub `redis` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis)?

Comment: yes, gone through it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to install redis completely.
This is the command

```
RUN apt-get install redis
```

Since redis-server was not installed, it was saying that Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379.